# In objective-C (iphone), how do I manage the memory of '@protocol' references?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I thought I had a pretty good handle on memory management for objective-c, but I can't figure out the following situation:

---

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@end
```

---

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    id<MyProtocol> reference;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<MyProtocol> reference;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation MyObject 
@synthesize reference;
-(void) dealloc {
    [reference release];
    [super dealloc];
}
...
@end
```

---

This gives me a "**warning: '-release' not found in protocol(s)**". 
Can I safely ignore this error? Or am I doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes you can safely ignore this error. An object declared as type `id<MyProtocol>` may not inherit from `NSObject` (you do not *have* to use the Cocoa libraries to program in Objective-C and there are other root classes even in Cocoa such as `NSProxy`). Since `retain` (and `release`, `autorelease`) are declared in `NSObject`, the compiler cannot know that the instance declared as type `id<MyProtocol>` responds to these messages. To get around this, Cocoa also defines the `NSObject` *protocol* which mirrors the `NSObject` API. If you declare your protocol as

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
@end
```

indicating that `MyProtocol` extends the `NSObject` *protocol*, you'll be set.

Answer (score 13):

Ordinarily, when you declare an object as `id` it counts an an "any" object (meaning that Objective-C will let you invoke any method from any class or protocol on the `id` without warning).

However, when you declare an object as `id<SomeProtocol>`, the meaning changes. In this case, you are instead saying: I will only invoke `SomeProtocol` methods on this object.

The method:

```
- (void)release;
```

is declared in the `NSObject` protocol but you have explicitly stated: I will only invoke `MyProtocol` methods. So the compiler gives you a warning to tell you that you've broken your own promise.

Therefore, instead of:

```
id<MyProtocol> reference;
```

you should actually declare:

```
id<MyProtocol, NSObject> reference;
```

or:

```
NSObject<MyProtocol> reference;
```

since `NSObject` (the class) implements `NSObject` (the protocol).

or:

```
id reference;
```

which is the broadest of the lot: let me invoke anything on this object and never complain.

You can also (as Barry Wark suggested) have `MyProtocol` include the `NSObject` protocol -- although from a design perspective, you normally only do this if implementing `MyProtocol` necessarily means using `NSObject`. Normally, we only do this if `NSObject` and `MyProtocol` are linked heritarily or semantically.

---

A little information about the `NSObject` protocol:

Everything you invoke retain/release/autorelease upon must implement this protocol. As you can infer from this: basically everything implements the `NSObject` protocol (even though a few things don't descend from the `NSObject` base class).

Another quick clarification: `NSObject` (the class) and `NSObject` (the protocol) are not reimplementations of the same API. They are split as follows:

- NSObject (protocol) implements everything required to handle/inspect an existing object in a generic sense (retain/release, isEqual, class, respondsToSelector: etc).
- NSObject (class) implements less generic methods: construction/destruction, thread integration, scripting integration.

So in most senses, the protocol is the more important of the two. Remeber that the class includes the protocol so if you descend from NSObject, you get both.

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<MyProtocol> reference;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyProtocol> reference;
```

Why bother to retain the object implementing the protocol? All you need is a pointer to the object by which we can call methods declared in your protocol.

Comment: You can't assume he doesn't needs to retain the object without more context.